# ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location) while deploying cloud function

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have to deploy a cloud function on gcp and it gave me importing error of bigquery form google.cloud even I have install all the requirements. This is the gcp cloud function interface in the image

[image: 1]

Comment: Most likely you are using a deprecated package. Make sure the library package you are using is current and supported.

Comment: Do you use **google-cloud-bigquery** package in requirements.txt file?